# Converting excel to pdf returns wrong file using MS Graph

Tags: javascript, excel, pdf, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using MS Graph API to convert excel to pdf.

But the pdf file I get from MS Graph API is different from the file I get from printing of Excel.

For example: My excel has only 2 pages, when I use excel to print PDF, I get exactly 2 pages, but  when I use MS Graph API to convert excel to pdf, my pdf file has 4 pages.

This is my js code to convert excel to pdf, just only send http request as document:

```js
export const convertPDF = async (token: string, fileID: string): Promise<ArrayBuffer> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    const baseUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/${fileID}/content?format=pdf`;
    axios
      .get(baseUrl, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
      })
      .then((response): void => {
        resolve(response.data);
      });
  });
};
```

- This is my excel file (**2 pages**): [SocialInsuranceDisqualification (2).xlsx](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/files/3839758/SocialInsuranceDisqualification.2.xlsx)
- This is pdf file from MS Graph API (**4 pages**): [416d334b-00db-4535-a56e-bf9254e6a56e.pdf](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/files/3839764/416d334b-00db-4535-a56e-bf9254e6a56e.pdf)
- This is pdf file from using printing function of Excel: (**2 pages**): [SocialInsuranceDisqualification (2).pdf](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/files/3839768/SocialInsuranceDisqualification.2.pdf)

Comment: Your Excel file has 4 pages on my machine. Pagination depends on a number of factors, not the least being the printer you're sending it to. This conversion API is not a replacement for printing, the API doesn't know what device your printing to and therefore just can't be as precise.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thanks for your comment. I changed the excel file to 2 pages and the result from `Save as` function of native Excel app show 2 pages [SocialInsuranceDisqualification (2).pdf](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/files/3844906/SocialInsuranceDisqualification.2.pdf), but pdf from MS Graph API still has 4 pages

Comment: Again, that "page" is dependant on the printer you're using. Excel will adjust pages based on the printer it is being sent to. I suspect that since there isn't a printer at all, it is resetting the print settings to default.

Comment: So how I can adjustment page number of output pdf by MS Graph API ? Even I modified Excel file to 2 pages, and the pdf from *Save as PDF* and *Print* function of Excel show 2 pages, the result pdf from MS Graph API still has 4 pages. Basically currently I can’t control the output layout by using MS Graph API

Comment: That is correct, there is no mechanism for fine-tuning the output.

Comment: So the pdf from MS Graph API isn’t depends on excel file? That’s really funny. Do you have any suggestions for my problem ?