# Convert Excel to PDF programmatically

Tags: excel, pdf, converters

I see some about converting excel to pdf on Window.

But I don't want to use windows for reasons.

I am using  (docker, deploy using k8s....).

How can I convert excel file (`xlsx`) to pdf.

I am ok using any language.

Comment: Yeah I did some research, I tried with Ruby and Python, Nodejs without success. Currently, I'm using Microsoft Graph API, its work very well until I got problem with paging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831838/converting-excel-to-pdf-returns-wrong-pdf-file

Comment: Some solution in Python but still using window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854840/xlsx-and-xlslatest-versions-to-pdf-using-python/20867193#20867193

Comment: Try openpyxl a python lib. It works for both on linux and windows. 
Also please understand that you cannot really search for excel and not find windows inside the links. Try searching for apache open office.

Comment: I tried with apache open office before, it seems like it only supports `odt` format (OpenOffice, Libreoffice). I converted `xlsx` to pdf by apache open office and the pdf layout was broken

Comment: I think you should refactor this question and add the code of the openpyxl. Please mention everything(the code, how the files are stored etc). So we can reproduce the problem.